# Why is my NSMutableDictionary null?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Here's my delegate method for UIAlertView. I have no idea why myWordsDictionary is null when running the app. (Note: _dailyWords is an NSDictionary object and bookmarked is an NSString object.)

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
        NSLog(@"Clicked button index !=0");
        // Add the action here
        NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)  lastObject];
        NSString *myWordsPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyWords.plist"];
        NSMutableDictionary *myWordsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myWordsPath];
        [myWordsDictionary setValue:[_dailyWords objectForKey:bookmarked] forKey:bookmarked];
        [myWordsDictionary writeToFile:myWordsPath atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@", [myWordsDictionary description]);
        [myWordsDictionary release];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Clicked button index = 0");
        // Add another action here
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because either `MyWords.plist` is nonexistent at the path you're trying to access it, or its root element is not a dictionary but an array.

Comment: once log all the documentPath and myWordsPath and can you please paste the log here..

Comment: /Users/seokhyeonchoi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/CAAF196E-7383-4178-B469-38ABEB51BC48/Documents,                    /Users/seokhyeonchoi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/CAAF196E-7383-4178-B469-38ABEB51BC48/Documents/MyWords.plist

Comment: (gdb) po bookmarked
abandon
(gdb) po [_dailyWords objectForKey:bookmarked]
v/n. [ abandon : inhibition :: calmness : frenzy ]

Comment: The above two comments are the Logs and a key-value pair to be written in myWordsDictionary. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

`myWordsPath` may not contain any valid file, and you are initializing your `NSMutableDictionary` from content of the the file present at that path. That's why you are getting a null dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First, try check `myWordsPath`, if it returns null, you should look and find correct path.

Second, how you generate your plist? `MyWords.plist` must contain valid format. If you unsure, you should create from within XCode, there is plist object.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:
                       @"MyWords" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                            initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

**please try this code..**

```
NSString *documentPath =    [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES)  objectAtIndex:0];
documentPath =    [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyWords.plist"]; 
NSMutableDictionary *myWordsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]    initWithContentsOfFile:documentPath];
```